# Selecting multiple tables MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm using *MySQL connector C 6.0.2*, I need to select Table1 and read some values there then switch to table2 and read the values there too etc, I have more than two tables I need to switch from table to table. How can I do this ?

example code:

```
connect=mysql_real_connect(connect,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0);
if(connect)
{
    MYSQL_RES *res_set; 
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    ////table1 
    mysql_query(connect,"SELECT * FROM `Table1` WHERE `Column2`='1234'");
    unsigned int i = 0; 

    res_set = mysql_store_result(connect);

    unsigned int numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set); 
    if(numrows==0)
    {
        return false;
    }else
    {
        while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set)) != NULL)
        {   
            if(strcmp(row[2], "true")==NULL)
            {/////////Here I need to read or get the values from Table2
                ///Select table two

            }else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** I think I have solved it, it was pretty simple

```
connect=mysql_real_connect(connect,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0);
if(connect)
{
    MYSQL_RES *res_set; 
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    ////table1 
    mysql_query(connect,"SELECT * FROM `Table1` WHERE `Column2`='1234'");


    res_set = mysql_store_result(connect);

    unsigned int numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set); 
    if(numrows==0)
    {
        return false;
    }else
    {
        while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set)) != NULL)
        {   
            if(strcmp(row[2], "true")==NULL)
            {/////////Here I need to read or get the values from Table2
                ///Select table two
                MYSQL_RES *res_set2; 

                ////table2 
               mysql_query(connect,"SELECT * FROM `Table2` WHERE `Column2`='1234'");


               res_set2 = mysql_store_result(connect);

              unsigned int numrows2 = mysql_num_rows(res_set2); 
              if(numrows2==0)
              {
                 //no result
              }else
              {
                 //do something
              }
            }else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you describe doesn't sound like the SQL way of doing it. You might want to provide more information on the tables to be queried, and the expected result. (Relevant columns and some sample data…) The SQL, we could suggest on that basis, might be much more efficient.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MySql, basically what I want to do is just read or get the values from table1, table2..etc in one function. What I did is made another function to get values from table2.

Comment: I highly recommend testing your SQL statement using the MySQL "command line" tool, mysql.exe, before putting it into your C++ code.  This will help define the scope of your issue:  SQL syntax or C++ issue.

Comment: If you are using C++, you should be using the C++ connector.

Comment: If the tables are not related to one another (in the sense, the stuff, you retrieve from Table1 has no impact on what you retrieve from Table2) - separate functions would make a lot of sense to me. If, however, you retrieve something from Table1, which affects, what you try to get from Table2, combining the requests into a single one would be my first choice.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `res_set` variable that you got from your query; you'd get another variable from your second query. You don't switch between tables, you just get the right values from the right query results.

Also note that this sounds a lot like you should be doing this inside your SQL query, and not inside your code, but that entirely depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you play with your SQL statement to return the result sets from both tables.

Research the "SELECT JOIN" statement.

The rule of thumb is to have the data perform most of the database work, including searching multiple tables.